# Android: Dynamically placing buttons on a canvas

Tags: android, dynamic, button, canvas

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

I'd like to know if it is possible for me to dynamically create a button and place it on top of a canvas given an x, y for button position.

I have an image that's 2,000px by 1600 px or so, I have the ability to scroll around this image.  I would like to place a button at say (100, 100)px with a pivot in the center of the button (say it's 50x50px) from within the activity.

The solution needs to be density and resolution independent...  Any thoughts?

Thanks again!!

Comment: Does the button have to be drawn on the canvas or just as an overlay?

Comment: Shouldn't matter.  Overlay would work as long as the button is in the same spot I want it on the canvas.  

A little more info, this is an app for a college, I'm putting buttons on their campus map for them to click for more information.

Comment: If you have reasons for or against using an overlay, I'd love to hear them :)

Comment: An overlay wouldn't get in the way of your map drawing code but it could be trickier to place it at the right coordinates.

Comment: The less tricky it is to place buttons at the proper coordinates the better.  I have about 20-30 locations to plot on this image. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing a `android.widget.Button` inside a canvas probably will not work(with all buttons events etc working). As `android.widget.Button` is not a "canvas object". Placing a `android.widget.Button` on Top of a canvas will work (but then you don't need the canvas at all).
Placing and android.widget object to a layout at a obsolete position cannot be done directly. You can only place ,for eg., the object at top-left position and then increase the margins do the `android.widget` will distance the anchor position.

If you want to play with canvas and positions directly create sprites. I would recommend a game engine for that thought like andengine.

Comment: I need the canvas to allow for scrolling - horizontal, diagonal, vertical. Using screen and img src rects then handling user input to move it around.  So my best bet would be to place buttons and increase margins?  Which unit should I use, sp?  
This isn't for a game it's for a college campus map with clickable buildings for more info...

Comment: dp. but i would recommend to create sprites. You own "buttons" with your events. Playing with margin is really a very sloppy work. Anything can go wrong. Create a canvas img to the canvas and detect clicks of the bitmap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447564/detect-touch-on-bitmap

Comment: As I mentioned before though I would be handling 20-30 different 'buttons' or sprites.  Won't this create a major performance issue?

Comment: i don't think so. 20-50 rectagles with a text or a low res bitmap will not be a problem at all.

Comment: Alright thank you for your help.  If you think of any other suggestions let me know!