# How to drag multiple bitmaps on Android Surfaceview

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am using a SurfaceView and have drawn multiple bitmaps to the view. My question is **how can I use the *Touch Listener* to target each bitmaps move action independently?**

Basically I want the user to be able to arrange the bitmaps in any order they like. I came up with a method of determining the space utilized on the SurfaceView for each bitmap and then checking the x and y values of the touch listener to determine if the user was selecting a known location of the bitmap. The problem I am having is that if bitmaps end up crossing each other then they stick together as they share the same space.

I am thinking there is probably a simpler way to handle the events of multiple bitmaps, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to select the bit map
follow the link for further detail.
[Detect touch on bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447564/detect-touch-on-bitmap)