# How to know which bitmap on canvas is touched?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas, draw

I have an array of bitmaps `myBitmapArray` that are drawn on canvas randomly. I have a random variable `Random rnd = new Random();` and each time the `onDraw` method is called (with a rate of 10 frames per second), I perform this code: `canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmapArray.get(rnd.nextInt(6)), x + xSpeed, y + ySpeed, null);` where `xSpeed` and `ySpeed` are used to change the location of every bitmap on the canvas. Bitmaps are drawn as expected.

I also use the `onTouchEvent` to play some sounds according to the bitmap touched (e.g. if the bitmap touched is a character, then that character is pronounced). My problem is in performing this task.

I know that I need to check that the touch event x and y are inside the bitmap image but since  I draw the bitmaps randomly, I don't know how to get their coordinates to make it possible to check.

Any idea on how I may solve this issue?

FYI: I have checked this question but without much help: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447564/detect-touch-on-bitmap)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep track of the X and Y position of your bitmap. Otherwise its impossible to know where your bitmap is drawn. Once you have your X and Y position of bitmap you can put the logic you have found and provided the link in your question.

Comment: Does this mean I can't place by bitmaps on the canvas in such a random way to be able to track each one of them?

Comment: You can draw/place your bitmap anywhere on the screen but Android will not be able to give you the X/Y position by any API or method. You have to take care of your own things. By keeping the X/Y position somewhere in your code.