# Can only move bitmap down and sideways Android

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I'm trying to move a bitmap only when the user touch moves from the bitmap itself, it works for moving downwards and sideways but It doesn't work when I try move the bitmap upwards.

Currently I have on my on touch:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent m) 
    {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int Xtouch = (int) m.getX();
    int Ytouch = (int) m.getY();

    switch(m.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:       
        if(Xtouch >= x && Xtouch < (x + ball.getWidth())
        && Ytouch >= y && Ytouch < (y + ball.getHeight()))
        {
            x = Xtouch;
            y = Ytouch;
        }
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

x and y are my bitmap's co-ordinates and ball is my bitmap. What I currently have only carries out the behaviours described in the title. I'm sorry I can't really be any more specific with my problem but it would be a major help if anyone can spot any potential silly errors I have?

Thanks

EDIT:

this is how I create the bitmap:

```
 ball= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
```

I initially set the x and y of the bitmap to 0.

This is how I draw the bitmap:

```
 c.drawBitmap(ball, x - (ball.getWidth()/2),  y-(ball.getHeight()/2), null);
```

This draws on the top left of the canvas, using the centre of the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

**This is wrong (see edit):**

More information would be helpful if you can, but my guess is that int this if:

```
    if(Xtouch >= x && Xtouch < (x + ball.getWidth())
    && Ytouch >= y && Ytouch < (y + ball.getHeight()))
    {
        x = Xtouch;
        y = Ytouch;
    }
```

the bit `Ytouch >= y && Ytouch < (y + ball.getHeight())` should read `Ytouch <= y && Ytouch > (y - ball.getHeight())` since graphics usually have the point `(0,0)` in the top left corner of the screen. Again, more info would be nice as this is a bit of a shot in the dark.

**EDIT:**

I am probly too tired to be on stack exchange right now. The above answer is wrong. Feel free to **downvote this**. For a moment I was thinking that y went negative as you went down which is exactly the confusion I thought you had mad in your code.

Comment: The suggested edit caused nothing to work :) I have added some extra maybe useful info to the OP :)

Comment: I should be more specific, nothing as in now I can't move the ball in any direction! :)

Comment: Also, the if-statement was obtained from this post :) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447564/detect-touch-on-bitmap