# How to select touch part of image, make Points Array of touched location of image in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[image: IMAGE A]

[image: IMAGE B]

[image: IMAGE C]

[image: IMAGE D]

I can successfully remove background from image. Now I need to select image wherever user touch and copy those area along with removed background of image. I have attached images of expected outputs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this using canvas. here is a repos link see : https://github.com/dung8910/BackgroundRemover

in this you can remove background undo,redo,sizes etc.
almost all background things cover in it.

Comment: Thank u so much for your reply. Let me try this one.

Comment: Btw I can successfully remove bg, now I want to keep certain portion of image by selecting from original image. I have shown in above image, what the scenario I'm trying to achieve. So how to get that thing done?

Comment: i think get matrix of touch event and draw bitmap through canvas

Comment: It's not working still.

Comment: try  last answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447564/detect-touch-on-bitmap